# JBPM - How to use CMT Command within a process

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I am trying to create a merge tool to merge multiple different branches together through SVN.

I am wanting to use JBPM running through AS7.
I am using JBPM 5.4 as it is the highest version that is compatible with my enviroment.

If it is run once, it works fine. However, when it is run more than once. If it gets to a human task, it will pause and wait for that human task to be complete. When the task is resolved it appears to look for a Ksession but it finds the first run throughs session and carries on from there using the first runs session.

It seems as if it isn't disposing of the ksessions.

I have come across [CMTDispose](http://planet.jboss.org/post/dispose_session_in_cmt_environment;jsessionid=ABD191959760F400D857A9FDA5DB0058). However I am not sure how to make it run in the AS7 as I need to call

```
ksession.execute(new CMTDisposeCommand());
```

Although I am not sure where I can call ksession within the process?

Any help would be good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Container-managed transactions work by simply making sure a transaction is already active when invoking the jBPM engine, in which case the engine will join the existing transaction.

At the end of the transaction, the state of all process instances is stored in the database.  If they are needed later, the state will be restored from the database again to continue where they left off.

It's unclear what's going wrong to give more concrete advice.

Comment: Its ok :). I was wanting to use it to dispose of the ksessions. I worked around it by creating a listener on the ksession and using the ~afterFinished~ method call to tell another thread to wait x amount of time and then dispose of the ksession and hthandler. I will write the answer up when i get time :)